# After fresh install of 22.04, I cannot JOIN 2 DISPLAYS

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 22.04

I have a Dell Inc. 30" monitor and a Samsung Electric Company 32" monitor per the Displays setting.  Apparently Ubuntu 22.04 sees both monitors as they are both listed in the Displays setting screen but when I try to click on JOIN DISPLAYS and click the APPLY button the setting reverts to Single Display.  My primary monitor is the Dell Inc. 30" monitor.  Has anyone else experienced this?  My previous install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS worked fine.  Any suggestions on how I can fix this?  I've been googling for this issue but to no avail.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the output of `xrandr -q` and paste it into your question? (with both monitors connected)

Comment: Did the Keep Changes dialog appear? If so, were you able to select Keep Changes? After hitting Apply, the new settings will be applied for 20 seconds before reverting back. If the Keep Changes dialog did not appear then there may be some issue with the graphics settings.

Answer (score 2):

I too had same issue. I am on ubuntu 22.04 (Had n nvdia driver)
This helped me to solve the issue.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then ,

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-dkms-510
```

Restarted the sytem, it worked fine for me.

This is my driver detail which worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My husband was able to find the issue.  I have an NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] video card for my 2nd monitor.  My system was using the MANUALLY INSTALLED NVIDIA driver which was ultimately the problem.  He removed the NVIDIA drivers and re-installed them using the ADDITIONAL DRIVERS in the apps section of Ubuntu 22.04.  My system is NOW using the NVIDIA Corporation: GK208B [GeForce GT 710] driver and NOT the manually installed NVIDIA driver and that fixed my issue.  Thanks kanhekili and binarystone for responding.  I appreciate you both for taking the time and help to respond.  Hopefully this might help someone else who might have the same issue I had.